# odd raw file corruption

Tags: raw, data-corruption

I am finding a small number of partially corrupted RAW files in my LR catalog.In short small "blocks" of each image that are randomly colored - often pink/red. Any ideas as to what might be the issue? Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Have you try to export them to understand if corruption is in the catalog preview or in original file?

Comment: Have these images always been corrupt (since import)? Or were they once fine and have only recently been corrupted?

Answer (score 4):

My first guess off the top of my head is corrupted SD card (or similar media) because it reminds me of a similar problem I once had because of one.

The card itself was fine after I reformatted it. It was my habit of deleting files off the card that most likely caused the corruption.

Anyway, swapping memory cards is about the simplest thing that might work. So that is another reason for starting with it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, All!
After a bit more digging...
The corruption IS in the .dng files, so not in the LR previews. So suspect it is a hardware problem.

I have about 50K images (from 2005 to today) and so far have discovered 27 with this corruption artifact. What concerns me is that I don't know if the problem occurred during import - or worse, if it is an ongoing and developing issue due to a progressive problem with the drives I use - meaning I could expect more files to become corrupted over time. So my new question relates to back-up strategies.

I keep the working folders of images on an external Samsung T7 SSD. I back up to two older Samsung T5 SSDs as well as to a spinning Seagate HD, a spinning drive on a Synology NAS, and finally to Backblaze and Amazon Photos. I've compared these images on all the back-up devices and they ALL contain the corruption.

Therefore, if this IS an ongoing and progressive problem with the primary working SSD drive, seems I am certain to overwrite uncorrupted files on the backups with corrupted files, each time I back up. Is there a better back-up solution? For the local back-ups I've used GoodSync - but of late have been using Carbon Copy Cloner. Thinking I need to learn how to tell CCC "don't overwrite existing files."

And along those lines I believe I have discovered why the Backblaze back-ups were taking forever (as in a week to complete!) I had checked the LR Catalog Setting box to "Automatically write changes into XMP". Which meant that each time I adjusted an image in LR, it would update the "Date Modified" of the .dng file. And hence, Backblaze figured that version needed to be uploaded. And given that I am in the process of a massive keywording project, tens of thousands of image files get flagged for backing up.

Thanks again, all...

Comment: I would not recommend backing up to SSD. Are these powered? Or completely disconnected?